# Date difference in ms access between row in report

Tags: ms-access-2016, date-difference

I have a table named `CustomerLog` with field following

```
ID    CustomerID      BuyingDate
1     1001            12/02/2020(dd/mm/yyyy)
2     2023            10/02/2020
3     2024            14/02/2020
4     1001            11/03/2020
5     2023            12/03/2020
6     2024            20/03/2020
7     1001            23/04/2020
8     2023            23/04/2020
9     2024            25/04/2020
```

Now I need a query like following

```
ID    CustomerID      BuyingDate      Difference
1     1001            12/02/2020      0
4     1001            11/03/2020      28
7     1001            23/04/2020      43
```

It will be very helpful if anyone can provide an example file for the cause I have read some post about this type but can't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to use a sub-query to get the previous date for the customer. You will also need to use the `Nz` (Null to Zero) function to set the first previous date for each customer to be the same as the buying date, and then use `DateDiff` to get the difference in days. Your SQL should look something like:

```
SELECT 
    C.ID, 
    C.CustomerID, 
    C.BuyingDate, 
    Nz((SELECT TOP 1 C1.BuyingDate FROM CustomerLog AS C1 WHERE C1.CustomerID=C.CustomerID AND C1.BuyingDate<C.BuyingDate ORDER BY C1.BuyingDate DESC),C.[BuyingDate]) AS PreviousDate, 
    DateDiff("d",PreviousDate,C.BuyingDate) AS Difference
FROM CustomerLog AS C;
```

Regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you guys.